# How can I pass props in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I started learning typescript and I can't figure out how to pass props.
I have a movie search, so I have a next component chain:
App -> Hero(a huge div which displays everything) -> Container(a container which contains divs with movies in each one) -> MovieItem(a div which contains all info about the movie, which we get from the json data).

I made the next interface:

```
export interface IMovie{
    rate: string;
    title: string,
    tagline: string;
    date: string;
}
```

Edit: I edited the code from the answers and that's what it looks like now:

App component:

```
    const App = () => {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieProps[]>([]);

  useEffect(() =>{
      fetchMovies();
  }, [])

  async function fetchMovies() {
      try{
        let apikey = '0ce1e51fc4f5b92e2f8984a6aa026503';
        let url: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=';
        url = url + apikey;
        const response = await axios.get<MovieProps[]>(url);
        setMovies(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);

      }catch(e){
        alert(e)
      }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Hero movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hero component:

```
const Hero = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="hero">
        <h1>trending today</h1>
        <Container movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Container component:

```
const Container = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <MovieItem movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

I passed props all the way through to MovieItem, but here's the problem, in App.tsx component I can't pass the array, because when I try to pass to the Hero component in the following way: `<Hero movies={movies}/>`,
I get the next error:

```
Type 'MovieProps[]' is not assignable to type 'MovieType[]'.
  Type 'MovieProps' is missing the following properties from type 'MovieType': rate, title, tagline, date
```

I created an `index.d.ts` file to store all the interfaces, it looks like this:

```
declare module 'myMovies' {
    type MovieType = {
        rate: string,
        title: string,
        tagline: string,
        date: string,
    };

    interface MovieProps {
        movies: MovieType[],
      }
    }

    module.exports = {
        MovieType,
        MovieProps
    };
```

So I'm not sure what could be the problem, I declared a default array in `useState()` and tried to pass to the Hero component.

Comment: Well, you have a typo there – `movie: IMovie[]` in `movieProp` should probably be `movies: IMovie[]`?

Comment: yeah, i actually had the typo, but now i have an error in an App, i pass props through Hero component with movies={movies} and it says `Type '{ movies: IMovie[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` Could it be the problem?

Comment: That's a `<Hero>` component, not your `<MovieItem>` component. You're not showing us how `<Hero>` works or which props it might accept.

Comment: i edited my original post. i added props to all components, but i still can't pass them from App to Hero because of the error in the post

Comment: You shouldn't use an `index.d.ts` file at all, for one...

Comment: i shouldn't? i'm new to typescript so i just searched how can i store multiple interfaces, and it was the result xd

Comment: You use .d.ts (declaration) files to declare the types for (JavaScript) libraries that don't have types to begin with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typings seem to be confusing a single movie and your props type, which has an array of multiple movies.

You also don't need an `index.d.ts` file at all; in fact you shouldn't have one. (You could export your common types from e.g. a `types.ts` file.)

Here's an example where everything you have is in one file.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface MovieType {
  rate: string;
  title: string;
  tagline: string;
  date: string;
}

interface MoviesProps {
  movies: MovieType[];
}

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setMovies([{ rate: "8", title: "Hello", tagline: "Yes", date: "2021" }]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Hero movies={movies} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Hero({ movies }: MoviesProps) {
  return (
    <div className="hero">
      <h1>trending today</h1>
      <Container movies={movies} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Container({ movies }: MoviesProps) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {movies.map((movie) => (
        <MovieItem key={movie.title} movie={movie} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function MovieItem({ movie }: { movie: MovieType }) {
  return (
    <div className="movie">
      <span className="movie__title">{movie.title}</span>
      <span className="movie__title">{movie.tagline}</span>
      <span className="movie__title">{movie.rate}</span>
      <span className="movie__title">{movie.date}</span>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, it finally makes sense! i didn't pass props through typescript before so it was a huge headache for me

Answer (score 0):

I tend to simply define components' props directly:

```
const MovieItem = (props: movieProps) => { 
  const { movies } = props;
  ...
```

I alos notice that you have no 'movies' prop, only a 'movie' prop. Check your spelling

Comment: i edited my question, maybe it could clear out things. i removed the typo but some other errors are still present, and i can't figure out where they come from

Answer (score 0):

`try`

```
const MovieItem = ({movies}):({movies:movieProps}) => { 
  return (
    <div>
          {movies.map(movie =>  //and here I have an error Parameter 'movie' implicitly has an 'any' type.
      <div className="movie">
      <span className="movie__title">{movie.title}</span>
        <span className="movie__title">{movie.tagline}</span>
        <span className="movie__title">{movie.rate}</span>
        <span className="movie__title">{movie.date}</span>
        <button>Button</button>
  </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem with declaring props for functional components in Typescript is that the underlying implementation of react expects the props to extend from their native, which is the error you are getting.

A solution is to describe prop in the component's definition rather passing props interface to the component generator(`FC`)

Answer (score 0):

Besides your `movies` typo mentioned in the comments, you did not assign the props type in the argument.

```
import React from 'react'

export interface IMovie{
  rate: string;
  title: string,
  tagline: string;
  date: string;
}

interface movieProps{
  movies: Array<IMovie>
}

const MovieItem = ({movies}: movieProps) => {  //here i have an error `Property 'movies' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<movieProps>`
 return (
   <div>
        {movies.map(movie=>
          <div className="movie">
          <span className="movie__title">{movie.title}</span>
          <span className="movie__title">{movie.tagline}</span>
          <span className="movie__title">{movie.rate}</span>
          <span className="movie__title">{movie.date}</span>
          <button>Button</button>
          </div>
        )}
   </div>
 )
};
```

Comment: i see, i did it and it works in MovieItem component, but how could i pass an array from App to MovieItem. I've tried it through `<Hero movies={movies}` and then the same through container, but it doesn't work like in javascript

Comment: if you pass it from App to Hero, you have to do in Hero the same as I did here in MovieItem. And From Hero to another component (if you have one). And from there finally to MovieItem.

Comment: i actually did it, as you can see in the original edited post, and it seems to work, i added props to the hero component, but i still can't pass them from App to Hero